# How are date values returned in mysql via php

Tags: php, mysql, date, sqldatatypes

I have a quick question regarding the values returned form MySQL.

Within one of my tables, I have a column assigned the `date` data type. When information is inserted into the database, `curdate()` is automatically executed to insert the proper date.

That said, MySQL recognizes that value is a date. I have a php script that pulls that value and presents it to the user. Now, is that value a string from php's standpoint?

What I want to do is, if necessary I should say, use the pulled value and insert that into a new table (ex: 10/1/12 pulled by php and then inserted into a new table). If that's the case, can I simply put that value into the new table's column that is of data type `date`? Or will MySQL not recognize that as a date?

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: When you insert dates into MySQL they *have* to be strings. MySQL will then convert that into a date and store it, but this date has to be in `YYYY-MM-DD`. But before you do that, are you sure you *need* to do that? You're essentially inserting duplicated data into another table. And [denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) usually is not good.

Comment: I'm aware of that. The table I'm pulling the dates from is a temporary table - an auditing table if you will - that has the associated rows being dynamically created and deleted. It won't denormalize the database. It's hard to explain as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL is smart enough to cast strings into a date.  The string should be able to be just about any standard format and it will translate it properly.

EDIT: Sorry, I was incorrect.

You can use PHP or MySQL date parsing functions to handle this.  In PHP:

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['myDateField']));
```

Here is a list of valid date strings that strtotime can interpret: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Comment: Very nice - that's what I needed to know. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure about this? MySQL expects dates to be in `YYYY-MM-DD`, I highly doubt you can just throw anything at it as you seem to be implying. CC: @Mlagma

Comment: @NullUserException, sorry, you're correct.  I sometimes get my MS SQL and MySQL confused.  I'll update my answer...

Comment: @AdamPlocher IIRC MS SQL isn't that flexible either, or actually worse. You have to use something like `insert into ... convert(DateTime,'date_string_here', format)` where the last argument is an obscure format id that you have to remember.

Comment: @NullUserException not to get TOO far off-topic here, but that's not true.  MS SQL will automatically try to cast any varchar/string you throw at it into a date (if inserting or updating a datetime field).  Any of these formats are accepted: http://linesofcode.net/snippets/45

Comment: MySQL just expects a date string in the format of YYYY-MM-DD as NullUserException said, or you can use a MySQL function to parse your string into a valid DateTime.  The example I posted in my response would be a way to do it through PHP to generate the properly formatted string.

Comment: Just realized that - NullUserException was talking about MS SQL above.

Comment: @AdamPlocher Interesting. I haven't worked much with SQL Server, but I do remember those numerical formats and how you couldn't create your own (SQL Server 2008 and older). I thought you'd need them when inserting stuff too.

Comment: I think you're thinking of a Timestamp (instead of DateTime) field.  Those are a pain in the butt :).  Very much different than a MySQL "timestamp" field.  MS SQL Timestamp: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method DateTime::createFromFormat

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't consider that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use mySQL str_to_date() converts string to date...so you can directly save a string with mySQL with date format ("yyyy-MM-dd") and just cast it with mySQL method str_to_date().
[HERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not have a syntax for native dates. Instead, it casts dates from/to strings automatically using the default date format:

```
mysql> SELECT @@date_format, @@datetime_format;
+---------------+-------------------+
| @@date_format | @@datetime_format |
+---------------+-------------------+
| %Y-%m-%d      | %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s |
+---------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

... where the format codes are the ones explained in the documentation for the [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function. You can always control the cast yourself with e.g.:

- [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to convert from date to string
- [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert from string to date

Said that, the fact is that too many tools rely on `@@date_format` and `@@datetime_format` keeping their factory values so changing them for the whole system is likely to break a lot of stuff.

It'd be possible for a PHP extension to cast date columns into [DateTime](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects (you don't say which one you are using) but none of the built-in ones currently do it, which is a pity.